# Playing video games on pc with mac

Tags: windows-7, macos

Here is the setup:

Desktop pc running windows 7 with everything but the kitchen sink (i7, 32 GB Ram, gtx 970, etc) which I will have my games running on. 
MacBook Pro which I would like to play games on (note: I cannot install games on this laptop but have windows Remote Desktop pre installed)

I would like to play games on my Mac by remoting in to my desktop but I wonder how much I will be able to tell. Is there a better way around this? Basically I want to play games from my couch by accessing the hardware that is in my office (in another room but on the same home network). What is the best way to do this?

Comment: If your games are Steam-powered games, you may be able to use this: http://store.steampowered.com/streaming/.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Gaming through RDP (Remote Desktop Protocol) may or may not work, depending on a number of factors, but even if it does, it's not going to be pleasant for any kind of high-framerate modern game.  The delay caused by sending the screen graphics and sound to the remote machine and the input to the machine running the game make most modern games unplayable.

Simple games that are not graphics and speed intensive like card games, board games, etc. will work just fine.

If you want to run high framerate games on your laptop, it will need appropriate hardware locally, and you will need to install the operating system required by the game (you could use "dual booting" if you want to keep the current operating system as well).

Comment: Agreed, using Remote Desktop can be laggy itself. Your games will be unplayable unless it is a game like minesweeper. Internet, WiFi protocols and computers are not yet able to handle something like this. Soon, hopefully. Maybe, just maybe, you will be able to use Steam to stream your games.